# Python show real time print messages in PHP

Tags: php, python

I think this topic has been covered quite a few times, and while I have been able to get it working, there are some flaws with it I was hoping to get some help with.

As the topic describes, I'm looking for a way to get my python script printed messages to show up on my PHP website:

```
<?php $output=shell_exec("/usr/bin/python cgi-bin/script.py"); print_r($output);?>
```

A python script printing out the php code with flush() / ob_flush() such as:

```
print "<?php"
print "header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );"
print "echo 'text';"
print "flush();"
print "ob_flush();"
print "sleep(5);"
print "echo 'text';"
print "flush();"
print "ob_flush();"
print "}"
print "?>"
```

was able to solve it, and get my messages printed properly, however, because the messages are printed in the middle of my page, the footer on the page and everything below it isn't loading until the script has done everything and I was hoping there was a way around this?

Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: You should be returning a string instead of trying to print to stdout. PHP won't be able to read it otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't exactly know what you mean with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax. Have a php file with the exec command and load the result in  div.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path-to-file/file.php",
    type: "get",
    success: function(data) {
       $(".targetDiv").html(data);
    }
});
```

btw, have your php file echo output